# How to lock msgbox pop ups in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up an office prank for April Fools that when a question is answered wrong a pop up (Msgbox) will pop up and I want it so it doesn't go away. The idea is their screen would get clogged with these msgboxes till they get the questions right. I'm not sure how to accomplish this though. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the current code:

```
 Sub Button1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim Ret As Variant

'Lockout Functions
'Cancel = True

'Hal2001 Takes Over
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hal2001")
Sheets("Hal2001").Visible = True
Sheets("Hal2001").Select

Ret = MsgBox("Would you like to play a game?", vbYesNo)
Application.Speech.Speak "I'm sorry I cannot let you do that, Would you like to play a game?"

If Ret = vbNo Then
Application.Speech.Speak "Well I want to play a game, so we are going to play one"
Else
Application.Speech.Speak "Then Lets Begin"
End If

'First Question
a = Application.InputBox("The Declaration of Independence was signed on what day?")
If a = "July 2nd 1776" Then 'continue
Else
Do While a = Application.InputBox("The declaration of independence was signed on what day?") < 100
Application.Speech.Speak "Are you even trying?"
MsgBox "You really don't know when the Declaration of Independence was signed??"
Loop
End If

'Second Question
b = Application.InputBox("Finish this Sequence 1123_813__")
If b = "1123581321" Then 'Continue
Else
Do While b = Application.InputBox("Finish this Sequence 1123_813__") < 100
Application.Speech.Speak "10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1!"
MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong"
Loop
End If

'How about some music
Application.Speech.Speak "How about some music?"
Ret = MsgBox("How about some music?", vbYesNo)
If Ret = vbNo Then
Application.Speech.Speak "Too bad, here is one from the eighties you will like."
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0")
Else
Shell ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe -url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0")
End If


'Third Question
c = Application.InputBox("What are the next three numbers 1,4,9,16,?")
If c = "1,4,9,16,25,36,49" Then 'continue
Else
Do While c = Application.InputBox("What are the next three numbers 1, 4, 9, 16, ?") < 100
'Application.Speech.Speak "Terrible!"
MsgBox "Hi, you got that answer wrong. Don't you love these pop up boxes?"
Loop
End If

'Unlock/Return Control
Application.Speech.Speak "Congradulations! You survived our April Fools 
Joke! Happy April Fools!"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False
'Cancel = False
End Sub
```

Comment: :) this is like a guilty pleasure.. Unlike forms, you can only ever display 1 `MsgBox` from VBA (as it's not a multi thread language). You could just have a modeless form that stays on screen until user selects the correct answer. This you will have a `MsgBox` and a form displayed on the screen at the same time :D

Comment: What about a way to lock the pop up so it stays up till they get the question right?

Comment: Use a form. Have a `TextBox` for the user to answer the question and a button to submit the answer. If the answer isn't correct, have a `Label` at the bottom of your form where you can display msgs and don't close the form.. devil at work :D

Comment: Sounds good thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This example should help you:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestQuestion()

    Dim StopAfter As Long
    StopAfter = 100 'to stop after 100 times asking
    Do While Application.InputBox("The Declaration of Independence was signed on what day?") <> "July 2nd 1776" And StopAfter > 0
        Application.Speech.Speak "Are you even trying?"
        MsgBox "You really don't know when the Declaration of Independence was signed?"
        StopAfter = StopAfter - 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Love the `Speak` touch! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you an idea how this could be frustrating to someone:

**My sheet:**

[image]

**My Macro:**

```
Dim X As Double

Option Explicit

Sub Test()

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For X = 2 To 4
        Do While .Cells(X, 4) <> .Cells(X, 3)
            .Cells(X, 4) = Application.InputBox(.Cells(X, 2))
        Loop
    Next X
End With

End Sub
```

:)